# Followed all steps but not working virtual host in windows 7

Tags: windows, apache, windows-7, wamp, vhosts

Recently I've tried to create virtual host in windows 7 with wampserver latest version. I've changed configuration but now it's working as 'localhost'   but I've given different name like 'mydev.test' like that but it's not working as 'mydev.test' and which location I've set c:/wamp/www/MasteringLaravel/public/   it's working as localhost still ! But i want it as mydev.test I've wasted many times with it but nothing change have made.

here is my all config file:-

[Conf file](http://pastebin.com/YuGi6tmD/)

Comment: This post should help you do it properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: After doing following things nothing happend for me ! I've followed these steps fro your link first I've changed index.php change line 30:$suppress_localhost = true;

to $suppress_localhost = false;    and then made first host for local and second for my virtual host. and I've used 'mydev' as my virtual host it's not working and if i press localhost it's coming wamp\www\ directories ! o.O

Comment: Not wuite sure what you mean, but maybe you have damaged \wamp\www\index.php. Are you using notepad, or a decent text editor?

Comment: I'm using Sublime text 3 build 3065 :)

Comment: Have you also added `mydev` to your HOSTS file?

Comment: Of course I've added mydev to HOSTS file ! I don't know what is the problem exactly :(

Comment: Don't mind please, I wan to say that now if you have configured wamp server these files then give me a copy ? I will replace my files with yours ? If then too not work there is nothing to do ! :(

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste sections out of the link I gave you and just change folder names and the ServerName. Its not difficult

Comment: i'M sorry Dear bro :) ! For the F***king proxy ! It was happend with me ! Now it's fine and Virtual host working Perfectly !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After long experiment I've found my problem! From the configuration there was don't have any problems and the problem is that I've used proxy address in my browser that's why!

I was not able to get virtual host! It took 7 days!